# Background Image mapping in Reactjs with Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, background-image

everyone please advise, I have an array with images, and I've created a mapping content, however I can not put a Background Image, in styles of a component. Other array objects is properly working

```
{DlCards.map((mdlcard) => {
    return(
    <Grid
        item
        xs = {mdlcard.grid_xs} 
        sm = {mdlcard.grid_sm} 
        md = {mdlcard.grid_md}
        container
        justify = 'space-between'
        style   = {{
            width:      '25%', 
            marginTop:  60,
            backgroundImage: {mdlcard.background}
            
        }}>
```

Comment: `background-image` in CSS uses the syntax `background-image: url(<url>)`, you need to replicate that with your style there, aka `backgroundImage: `url(${mdlcard.background})`

Answer (score 1):

```
style   = {{
            width:      '25%', 
            marginTop:  60,
            backgroundImage: {`url(${mdlcard.background})}
            
        }}>
```

you missed the url

Comment: Thank you, very much

Comment: you are welcome. Can i get a up vote and right answer mark